# How to convert to_days function from Mysql to Oracle?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, date

I am using `to_days()` function in mysql as

```
to_days ( CURRENT_DATE  + interval '1' day )
```

Now I am deploying the same query on `Oracle` database, but oracleDB doesn't have a `to_days()` function.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, `to_days()` comphutes the number of days between the given argument and year 0 (`0000-00-00`).

The equivalent for:

```
to_days(current_date)
```

Should be, in Oracle:

```
trunc(sysdate) - date '0001-01-01' + 364
```

As of today, both expressions return `737854`.

Comment: date 0000 isn't valid

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: it seems to work in Oracle 11g, but not in 18c... I modified my answer accordingly.